# Android database access (simple and performant)

Tags: android

I'm currently playing around with the android API. Currently I'm doing a bit of GUI-database binding and I'm starting to get a bit annoyed.

I have a simple `ListActivity` with a custom layout for the list items. Now I want to bind the underlying `ListView` to a table in the database. Whenever I make changes to the database I want to be able to notify the ListView to refresh itself and update the GUI. At first, the problem look straightforward: just add a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, pass it a cursor for fetching the data, bind columns to layout ids and your down. Whenever you want to do a refresh simply call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the ListView and you are done, right? No!

Turns out, this way the database will be queried in the UI thread which is obviously a bad thing as it will degrade performance and could lead to "application not responding" errors.

Currently, it looks like the only way is to use Loaders and ContentProviders. This may be the most abstract and cleanest way to handle data access but it also adds a huge amount of code (especially in the ContentProvider itself where you have to do a lot of ugly if-else switch-case handling for "parsing" the requests).

So my question is: what is the state of the art (and backwards compatible to API level <11) way to connect a database table to a ListView (or any other UI components)? Do I really have to use a ContentProvider?

And why is this so complicated? I.e.: scanning for a bluetooth devices can be implemented in abaout 20 lines of code but for (from my perspective) much more common thing like data-ui-connection you have to implemented at least two classes which 100+ loc each. This is madness!

Comment: optimize your database so that queries are fast. Or, use an asynctask to make the query and replace the cursor (or the adapter).

Answer (score 0):

> ...but it also adds a huge amount of code (especially in the
>   ContentProvider itself where you have to do a lot of ugly if-else
>   switch-case handling for "parsing" the requests).

I don't see why would that happen. The code needed for implementing the `Loaders` in a `SimpleCursorAdapter` for a `ContentProvider` is instantiating a `CursorLoader` in `onCreateLoader`ans swapping the returned `Cursor` in the other two callbacks of the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` interface. In the provider you just need to use `setNotificationUri` on the `Cursor`.

> Do I really have to use a ContentProvider?

If you want to benefit from the `CursorLoader`refresing the data after the database was modified, yes. You could always take matters into your own hands and do the queries yourself.